Microsoft Graph API - Email messages with empty body content
I have an implementation where I consume a mailbox and move e-mails to specific folders based on some rules.
Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
For some months now, some e-mails stopped being processed, and we noticed that for a very specific sender, the e-mail body comes empty.
e.g:
 "body": {
            "contentType": "text",
            "content": ""
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "name",
                "address": "name@domain.com"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "name",
                "address": "name@domain.com"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "address": "name@domain.com"
                }
            }
        ],

I have no idea how to troubleshot this, as the customer showed me the mailbox and all the emails have content.
Anyone with the same issue?

are you requesting a specific body type (eg text) it maybe your getting some sort of content conversion error. The way to debug that would be to try asking for the html body instead.

Is bodyPreview also empty?

Change the type doesn’t help. It give mes an empty html as well. Body preview is also blank
